# How many levels has the arena mode in Hammerfight?

Tags: hammerfight

I've reached level 20 and I can't beat the enemies, is the end near?

Comment: If you're having trouble beating enemies, get some gems in hunt mode.  To unlock hunt mode, choose to go hunt the worms in Act 1.
The gems greatly increase the power of your weapons.  Another tactic you can try is lowering the DPI in the options menu, this will allow you to swing faster with less effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of arena levels is unlimited I believe. I'm up to 78 and the only difference seems to be the number of enemies you have to defeat to win. You reach a point where the difficulty no longer increases because the guys you face will be equipped with one of maybe 6 weapon loadouts. So long as you have a health gem in your weapon you can defeat them all without using any heal items.

Also, I've not noticed the game glitch in any harmful way. All that occurs is that you end up making too many fame achievements and coins to fit on the win screen, so the stuff at the top and bottom is hidden (drawn out of view). But you can just click like normal to go back to the menu.

Answer (score 0):

[nope](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0NFrEf3rdwY).  The link is a spoiler, but rest assured you have a ways to go.  And that's not even the end.

Comment: Just a note that the video's been taken down and so this answer no longer provides any information :P

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I could find:

> Arena: A series of arena fights against random opponents where you advance levels, each more challenging than the last. You receive rewards, like strong weapons, up until level 20, after which you rewards cease. **The game also seems to glitch once you reach level 48.**

From http://tig.wikia.com/wiki/Hammerfight